# Jupiter Tessellation(JT) files problem with LZMA Compression

Tags: c#, compression, lzma

I am working at JT reader. I make reader for JT V8.0 or V9.5. Now I trying to parse JT V10.0 or V10.5. But I faced problem with decompression data. For old version code was working without problems. I am using C#. This is specification for JT V10
https://www.plm.automation.siemens.com/en_us/Images/JT-v10-file-format-reference-rev-B_tcm1023-233786.pdf

When program find **Logical Element Header Compressed**(specification page 33) it cant decompress this. Error is in header.

I used SharpZipLib for decompression for JT V8.0,V9.5.

If someone has specification for JT files V8.0 or V9.5, it may help me.

I will be glad for any advice how to solve this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Despite the fact that in specification was written that they used **LZMA** compression, they used **XZ** compression or **LZMA2**. I found library [XZ.NET](https://github.com/RomanBelkov/XZ.NET). This library decompress or compress XZ compression.